# Firebase Dynamic Links do not work, does not generate link

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Hi I have an ios app where I use dynamic links to share content with users, I did not change anything in the app so it is not something in the code, I guess.

When I run the app the console shows me the following:

> Error Domain=com.firebase.durabledeeplink Code=0 "We could not match param 'https://www.example.com/post?postId=hy48ndmFLMdxydT7mGPq' with whitelisted URL patterns in this Google project. [https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429] [https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429]" UserInfo={remoteStatus=INVALID_ARGUMENT, NSLocalizedFailureReason=We could not match param 'https://www.example.com/post?postId=hy48ndmFLMdxydT7mGPq' with whitelisted URL patterns in this Google project. [https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429] [https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429], remoteErrorCode=400}

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try opening the Dynamic Link page on the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/durablelinks/), then click on the three-dot menu and select **Allowlist URL pattern**. If it's the first time you've opened it, it will want you to add a URL that matches your dynamic links, so just enter the initial URL of your deep link, like, "https://www.example.com/" (and click the check box).

That should generate a default regular expression for you, but it might not work because of the "post" in the link. So, after you've added an allowlist the first time, you should be able to re-open **Allowlist URL pattern** and that'll allow you to edit the regular expression to match your links. For example, if your link is `https://www.example.com/post?postId=hy48ndmFLMdxydT7mGPq`, try the following to fix it up:

`^https{0,1}:\/\/www\.example\.com\/post([\/#\?].*){0,1}$`